# Adding multiple options to fields at one go in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

It seems that because of **databases.xsd**,in **MarkLogic 7** you can't add all the different options to fields as part of the field xml during adding of fields, as you could in **MarkLogic 5** . 
Example:

```
 <three-character-searches> true </three-character-searches>
 <three-character-word-positions> true </three-character-word-positions>
 <two-character-searches> true </two-character-searches>
```

I have quite few options to add . What's the way to add them at one go rather than using APIs for each and every option ,such as,

> admin:database-set-field-stemmed-searches

etc.

**Edit**

The following piece of code does work on ML 5.0.5 .

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";

  import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $field:=<field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database">
      <field-name>myField</field-name>
      <include-root>false</include-root>
      <word-lexicons>
        <word-lexicon>http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</word-lexicon>
      </word-lexicons>
      <stemmed-searches>decompounding</stemmed-searches>
      <word-searches>true</word-searches>
      <fast-phrase-searches>true</fast-phrase-searches>
      <fast-case-sensitive-searches>true</fast-case-sensitive-searches>
      <fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>true</fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>
      <trailing-wildcard-searches>true</trailing-wildcard-searches>
      <trailing-wildcard-word-positions>true</trailing-wildcard-word-positions>
      <three-character-searches>true</three-character-searches>
      <three-character-word-positions>true</three-character-word-positions>
      <two-character-searches>true</two-character-searches>
      <one-character-searches>true</one-character-searches>
      <included-elements>
        <included-element>
          <namespace-uri>ns</namespace-uri>
          <localname>in</localname>
          <weight>9</weight>
          <attribute-namespace-uri/>
          <attribute-localname/>
          <attribute-value/>
        </included-element>
       </included-elements>
      <excluded-elements>
        <excluded-element>
          <namespace-uri>ns</namespace-uri>
          <localname>ex</localname>
        </excluded-element>
      </excluded-elements>
    </field>



let $config := admin:get-configuration()

let $config:=admin:database-add-field($config,xdmp:database(),$field)
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

Comment: MarkLogic 5 uses [admin:database-field()](http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0/admin:database-field) to construct a field, as does MarkLogic 7; that function doesn't take the full field config in either version. Can you clarify how you were creating fields using ML5?

Comment: Please take a look at the Edit part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's being particular about the order. I compared your code to what MarkLogic records when you create the field through the Admin UI. Based on that, I moved the <word-lexicons> further down.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $field:=
  <field xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <field-name>myField</field-name>
    <include-root>false</include-root>
    <stemmed-searches>decompounding</stemmed-searches>
    <word-searches>true</word-searches>
    <fast-phrase-searches>true</fast-phrase-searches>
    <fast-case-sensitive-searches>true</fast-case-sensitive-searches>
    <fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>true</fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>
    <trailing-wildcard-searches>true</trailing-wildcard-searches>
    <trailing-wildcard-word-positions>true</trailing-wildcard-word-positions>
    <three-character-searches>true</three-character-searches>
    <three-character-word-positions>true</three-character-word-positions>
    <two-character-searches>true</two-character-searches>
    <one-character-searches>true</one-character-searches>
    <word-lexicons>
      <word-lexicon>http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</word-lexicon>
    </word-lexicons>
    <included-elements>
      <included-element>
        <namespace-uri>ns</namespace-uri>
        <localname>in</localname>
        <weight>9</weight>
        <attribute-namespace-uri/>
        <attribute-localname/>
        <attribute-value/>
      </included-element>
    </included-elements>
    <excluded-elements>
      <excluded-element>
        <namespace-uri>ns</namespace-uri>
        <localname>ex</localname>
      </excluded-element>
    </excluded-elements>
  </field>

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $config:=admin:database-add-field($config, xdmp:database(), $field)
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

That worked.

Having said that, I feel compelled to point out that you're working around the API instead of with it, which feels brittle. Proceed with caution.

Comment: Thanks. I could not understand the "you're working around the API instead of with it" part . What should I do instead?

Comment: I mean that if you use the functions like `admin:database-set-field-stemmed-searches`, you're less likely to have an error creep in than if you pass a block of XML in. What you're doing isn't wrong, I just expect that with the current approach, you're more likely to see other errors than if you called the functions individually. That said, I get that you might need to call a lot of functions, which means a lot of code.

Comment: You could also consider using an existing tool that does this kind of work, like the [Roxy Deployer](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy) or [ml-gradle](https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle) (although ml-gradle requires ML7+.)

Comment: Got it. That's really something to consider. Thanks a lot.